# Angular5 TestBed useValue seems not injecting same object instance

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular5

While writing unit tests I hit to strange case for which I don't understand where the problem is.

I've prepared short code for reproducing:

*TestInjectable - simple injectable class*

```
@Injectable()
class TestInjectable {
  testProperty = 'testValue';
}
```

*TestComponent - small component that uses TestInjectable*

```
@Component({
  providers: [TestInjectable],
  template: ''
})
class TestComponent {
  constructor(private injectable: TestInjectable) {
  }

  doTest() {
    return this.injectable.testProperty;
  }
}
```

*Unit test*

```
describe('Test TestComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    let testInjectableMock: TestInjectable = new TestInjectable();
    testInjectableMock.testProperty = 'valueInMock';

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [{provide: TestInjectable, useValue: testInjectableMock}],
      declarations: [TestComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should do something', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent> = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    let component: TestComponent = fixture.componentInstance;

    expect(component.doTest()).toBe('valueInMock');
  });
});
```

Since I have `testInjectableMock` to which I set `valueInMock` I would expect that component would return this value. The problem is that component is returning `testValue` which is default value and test fails with:

> Expected 'testValue' to be 'valueInMock'.

It sounds like `TestBed` is creating another instance of `TestInjectable` even if I provided instance using `useValue` property.

```
providers: [{provide: TestInjectable, useValue: testInjectableMock}]
```

Has anyone idea if I missed something or where the catch is and how to convince `TestBed` to use mock instance?

Comment: Where do you have setTestProperty in your TestComponent ?

Comment: I don't. It's just called to set new value on mocked instance testInjectableMock.setTestProperty('valueInMock');

Comment: If you check example again, on mock instance testProperty is changed to new value. I expect that in component then mock instance is injected, but seems it is not.

Comment: I edited question and removed setter to avoid such confusion. Initial question remains...

Comment: Sorry I didn't look properly first time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular DI clones objects provided by `useValue` and from the looks of it, does it incorrectly:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10788

You should use factory instead:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [{provide: TestInjectable, /*-->*/ useFactory: () => testInjectableMock}],
  declarations: [TestComponent]
}).compileComponents();
```

Comment: Marked this one as accepted answer since we were all the time meanwhile using factory and this works as expected.

Comment: I just run into this with Angular 11. Even though 10788 should be fixed, I had to use `useFactory`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
describe('Test TestComponent', () => {
  let testInjectableMock: TestInjectable = new TestInjectable();

  beforeEach(async(() => {   
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [{provide: TestInjectable, useValue: testInjectableMock}],
      declarations: [TestComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should do something', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent> = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    let component: TestComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
    testInjectableMock.testProperty = 'valueInMock';
    expect(component.doTest()).toBe('valueInMock');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect even with the useValue you are not getting an untainted version of your testInjectableMock.

Try this?

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [{provide: TestInjectable, useValue: new TestInjectable()}],
      declarations: [TestComponent]
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {
      const testInjectableMock = TestBed.get(TestInjectable);
      testInjectableMock.setTestProperty('valueInMock');
    });
  }));
```